# How to configure fw-utils to store environment on FAT filesystem?

Tags: u-boot

I'm struggling with setting U-boot env variables from userspace using `fw_setenv`.

U-Boot uses the env variables stored on a file `u-boot.env` on `/dev/mmcblk0p1`. This is a FAT32 partition on a SD card.

I also have the tools `fw_setenv` and `fw_printenv` available in userspace. But I don't know how to configure `/etc/fw_env.conf` so `fw_setenv` stores the variables in above mentioned file.

I build U-boot 2015-07 with the am43xx_evm defconfig. Could someone help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, `fw_printenv` and `fw_setenv` are not designed to read and write configuration *files*: they act on a pseudo-partition whose offset is given in their configuration.

If you want to edit a plain U-Boot configuration file, you'll have to use more traditional tools.

Comment: I never thought about this option, but it make sense. I'm searching for days and didn't found any example of modifying env files with `fw_setenv` nor found any offsets in the am43xx. config

Comment: With "traditional tools" you mean a text editor @etene ?

Comment: That is an old question, but I'm pretty sure I was talking about using a text editor, yes. That's the traditional way of editing configuration files by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually the U-Boot environment is a database comprising key/value pairs where both `key` and `value` are strings.  In operation U-Boot works with a RAM copy of the environment.  The RAM copy can be persistently saved via a number of mechanisms and it can also be initially populated via a number of mechanisms.

There are two major types of persistent storage mechanisms.  The first is a direct write of a binary version to any of a multiple of storage device types (activated by the U-Boot command `saveenv`).  The second is to write to a text file via the `export` mechanism.

It appears that you are using this second method.

If using the first method, the device type, offsets, sizes, etc. are specified in a configuration file that is referenced during the compile process.  The tools `fw_printenv/setenv` are designed to work with this binary method.  They can be compiled with those same device types, offsets, sizes built in but by default, read those values from `etc/fw_env.config`.

Since you're using the second method, you can just work with the text file and don't need `fw_printenv/setenv`.

I've always preferred the first (binary) method when possible since

- it's protected by a CRC
- you can take advantage of support for a backup copy

Answer (score 1):

This is working in 2023, with some care and feeding.

Specifically, if you have a `u-boot.env` as described by the questioner, you need to modify your `fw_env.config` file to point at that file.

```
/tmp/u-boot.env 0x0000 0x40000
/tmp/u-boot.env 0x0000 0x40000
```

Yes, you want to have this line **twice** in the file, due to some bug or another.  Obviously the first argument is the path to the u-boot file (could be `/run/media/mmcblk1p1/u-boot.env` instead of `/tmp/u-boot.env`, or perhaps something else).  The second argument is the offset in that file you should use (for a FAT file, the offset will be 0 as listed).  Finally, the size of the environment file.  For me, the file was 256KB before I started playing around, so I replicated that.

Then you can call fw_printenv/fw_setenv as desired.  If you have a different configuration file for this, pass it as an argument:

```
fw_printenv -c /tmp/fw_env.config ethaddr
```

As noted, this works on the configuration environment which is typically found in QSPI at some address or another (but for SD/MMC boot can be read off of the far partition).  This doesn't work on the u-boot default environment source files.

Answer (score 0):

The board is supported in current U-Boot. There is not need to stay with a 2015 version.

The command to save the environment is *saveenv*.

A template for the configuration file for the fw_printenv tool is available in tools/env/fw_env.config of the U-Boot source.

Comment: I'm aware of `saveenv`, but this is a tool to save the environment from the U-boot console. I need to modify the environment from userspace.